# Как можно прочитать содержимое Excel файла GS

Tags: google-apps-script

Нужно извлечь данные из Excel файла, лежащего на Google Drive и использовать в скрипте. Как это можно сделать:

1. Я нашел варианты, что xls можно преобразовать в Google sheet. А  затем прочитать содержимое. На первый взгляд смотрится не элегантно.
2. Можно ли сразу не создавая Google sheet файла, прочитать содержимое xls файла? Идеально было бы получить некий массив массивов. Возможен ли такой вариант? И если да, то подскажите, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд кажется, что возможно создание какого-то канала для постоянного или поточного чтения данных. Но это не так. Для того чтобы соединиться с файлом данных даже на локальном компьютре требуется целый драйвер. С Диском Гугл все обстоит намного сложнее, т.к. внутри него все намного проще.

Поэтому оптимальным вариантом для решения подобной задачи является синхронизирование источника данных и Таблицы Гугл на стороне клиента. Т.о. у вас нет необходимости загружать файл на Диск, когда можно загружать данные в Таблицу или таблицу Fusion.

Но при этом могут существовать ограничения на работу с Диском (например файл данных приходит по почте или что-то в этом роде), тогда никаких вариантов, кроме дискового преобразования не остается.

Comment: Спасибо! Файл приходит по почте, сохранить его на диске не вижу проблем, а вот как прочитать содержимое?

Comment: И я не вижу проблем оформить топик согласно правилам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Вы ищите решения или того, кто его вам даст?

Comment: Я ищу решение, топик как смог формить, так и оформил. Возможно существуют какие-то готовые библиотеки или приложения на GS. Вот я их и ищу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask